# Creating a masterpage in Visual Studio .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Simple question, ok a **contentplaceholder** is implemented for Page-specific content.

What about header region, advertisment, recommended books, footer etc

1- What do you insert this as?

2- how do you adjust the size the way you want it?

[image]
<sub>(source: [asp.net](http://static.asp.net/asp.net/images/master-pages/01/Images/aspnet_tutorial01_Basics_cs_figure02.png))</sub>

Comment: +1 for the nice picture and clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Master Page with this layout would have only one ContentPlaceholder. The other parts you show are part of the Master Page, and they are handled by code of that page.

The pages which use this as their Master have only a ContentPlaceholder control, everything they do goes in there.

You can have multiple ContentPlaceholders. For example, on a recent project I had one on the left (for navigation) and one in the middle (for content). But your design seems not to need that.

Since this all turns into HTML in the end (the ContentPlaceholder is just a `div`), the size of the sections can be set by the Master Page or change on the fly. The page, for example, could tell the Master "no advertisements section on this page".

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple ContentPlaceholder controls on your master page if you have unique content to display based off of the page you are rendering.  Just give each ContentPlaceholder a unique ID.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) for more information.

You can control the layout and size of each ContentPlaceholder with CSS or in-line styling.